# How to BREAKING ROWS using TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I using direct way **[like](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_011.phps)** to make pdf faster. How to  `BREAKING ROWS` [like](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.pdf)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can be able to achieve this using "rowspan" and "colspan" attributes. exp:

```
&lt;table border="1"&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;
&lt;th rowspan="2"&gt;Rowspan 2&lt;br /&gt;This is some text that fills the table cell.&lt;/th&gt;
&lt;th colspan="2"&gt;span 2&lt;/th&gt;
&lt;th colspan="2"&gt;span 2&lt;/th&gt;
&lt;th rowspan="2"&gt;2 rows&lt;/th&gt;
 &lt;th colspan="8"&gt;Colspan 8&lt;/th&gt;
 &lt;/tr&gt;
 &lt;/table&gt;
```